# How can I get intraday prices for mutual funds?

Tags: mutual-funds

How can I get intraday prices of a mutual fund? (Mine are Oppenheimer funds.)

Comment: As others have pointed out, mutual funds calculate their "prices" at the end of each trading day.   Intraday pricing makes no sense, although if you knew all the assets of a fund you could do "real-time" valuations, but it is not likely that will happen.

Comment: @Tim. Even with that, we still got to subtract the funds liabilities. How do we know the fund's liabilities?

Answer (score 15):

Mutual funds don't have intraday prices. They have net asset values which are calculated periodically (daily or weekly or any other period depending on the fund).

Comment: If a mutual fund is also offered as an ETF (often the case at Vanguard) you can look at the prices for the ETF - they may trade at a slight premium or discount to the underlying holdings, but it works as an approximation.

Answer (score 6):

This idea does not make sense for most mutual funds.

> The net asset value, or NAV, is the current market value of a fund's holdings, minus the fund's liabilities, that is usually expressed as a per-share amount. For most funds, the NAV is determined daily, after the close of trading on some specified financial exchange, but some funds update their NAV multiple times during the trading day.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_fund

I am not certain, but I believe that OppenheimerFunds does not report intraday prices.  I would call them up and ask.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, mutual funds don't have an intraday NAV, but their ETF equivalents do. Use something like Yahoo Finance and search for the ETF.IV. For example VOO.IV. This will give you not the ETF price (which may be at a premium or discount), but the value of the underlying securities updated every 15 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Look at morningstar holdings.It will list the top 25 holdings and their current price.This will give you a good idea of the intra-day price of the fund.