# Why this mutual fund (VTTHX) is not traded today ?

Tags: trading, mutual-funds

As you may know the market is in panic today. However if you look for VTTHX, you will see it frozen since Aug 21. Did this fund magically escaped the panic ? what is going on ?

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/a/3549/24920

Answer (score 4):

Mutual Fund Net Asset Values are determined at the end of day.

You cannot trade Mutual Fund in real time.

There is no relation between the so-called "panic" and the mechanism of Mutual Fund.

If you wish to trade in real time, you may switch to ETF.